# Count different rows from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `t1`:

```
id|id_title|action
```

The data in table:

```
1|1|like
2|1|like
3|1|unlike
4|2|share
5|2|share
```

So I want to get next result from query:

```
id|count like|count unlike|count share

1|2|1|0
2|0|0|2
```

I try to use next query:

```
SELECT id_title, ( Select Count(id) From T1 WHERE action='like') As CountOfItems FROM T1 GROUP BY id_title
```

But it return count of first row always. What I must do? Or maybe I must changed structure of table?

Comment: I didn't understand what query you want to apply to the table, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id_title AS id, SUM(action='like') AS 'count like', 
SUM(action='unlike') AS 'count unlike', SUM(action='share') 
AS 'count share' FROM t1 GROUP BY id_title
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

Just use conditional aggregation.

```
select
id_title
,sum(case when action='like' then 1 else 0 end) As Count_Like
,sum(case when action='unlike' then 1 else 0 end) As Count_Unlike
,sum(case when action='share' then 1 else 0 end) As Count_Share
FROM T1 
GROUP BY id_title
```

Comment: or, as it's MySQL, just `SUM(action = 'like')`